# How do I show with the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ criteria that this function isn't continuous?

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

I would need to show that the function $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}~~~~~f(x)=0~\text{if} ~x<0, ~f(x)=2~\text{if} ~x\geq 0$$is not continuous at the point $x=0$ with the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ criteria  .

Here's what I've been thinking about. Let $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$, let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ choose $\delta>0$. Then we know that there exists $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$, thus take $x=-\frac{1}{n}\in \mathbb{R}$ and notice that $|x|<\delta$. But at the same time it holds that $$|f(x)-2|=|-2|=2>\epsilon$$ Therefore $f$ is not continuous according to the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ criterion.

**Remark** alternativly one could take $x=0.5\delta$, this would also work.

Is it possible to do it this way?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: My only caveat is that you would have to argue how you could extend the proof to any $\delta$, it isn't enough to show it for some.

Comment: @ManateePink but $n$ can be taken arbitrarly can't it?

Comment: Sure, so you have shown it for all $1/n$. But surely you agree there are more positive numbers than that, right? And $\delta$ has to be any positive number, not just $1/n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Couldn't I take $\delta>0$ arbitrary and then say that there is always an $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$ and then define $x=-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Exactly, that is what I meant. As a last comment, notice, that the proof becomes smaller if you just use something like $x=0.5\delta$.

Comment: ah perfect, but so then it would work?

Comment: Once you add the argument you made in the comments, yes, it works

Comment: I've added it above hope this is enough information for everyone who is interested in the solution.